# When I save the output of displacy.render(doc, style="dep") to a svg file, there is a TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Tags: python, spacy

I want to save the visualisation of spaCy with the code that spaCy offers here : https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers

Here is my code :

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u"Autonomous cars shift insurance liability toward manufacturers")
svg = spacy.displacy.render(doc, style="dep")
output_path = Path(os.path.join("./", "sentence.svg"))
output_path.open('w', encoding="utf-8").write(svg)
```

But when I execute this code, there is an error : TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

So how can I save the output of spacy.displacy.render ? How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Your code work for me - if I add all the imports (import spacy, from spacy import displacy, from pathlib import Path). I know this error if the line `svg = displacy.render(sentence_nlp, style="dep")` contains another attribute `jupyter=True` but this does not seems to me be the case as you d not have it here..

Comment: I have the same problem... did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 9):

The code provided in the question works fine, when executed in an IDE like PyCharm.

However, `displacy.render()` works slightly differently in a Jupyter notebook, cf the documentation [here](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers) and [here](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#jupyter):

> If you’re running a Jupyter notebook, displaCy will detect this and return the markup in a format ready to be rendered and exported.

You can overwrite this automated detection by explicitly setting `jupyter=False` in the `render()` call.

Comment: The official documentation addresses this question with this answer here - [Example: Export SVG graphics of dependency parses](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#examples-export-svg)

(I used jupyter notebook and this worked for me)